# Do something with each row and then get union of results - SQL (DB2)

Tags: sql, db2

I couldn't find solution for this problem.

I have table A with primary key ROW_ID, table B with same extern key and column SOMETHING.
Also, I have function created like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FIND_SOMETHING_FOR_ID(ROW_ID INTEGER)
RETURNS TABLE(SOMETHING INTEGER)
BEGIN ATOMIC
RETURN
    SELECT SOME_SCALAR_FUNCTION(SOMETHING)
    FROM B b
    WHERE b.ROW_ID=ROW_ID;
END@
```

The thing I want to do is: for each ROW_ID in A get table returned by FIND_SOMETHING_FOR_ID
and then get UNION of all tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafztabref.htm?lang=en), you can do what you want as:

```
select fsfi.*
from A a cross join
     table(find_something_for_id(a.row_id)) fsfi;
```

That is, a table-valued function can reference tables *before* it in the `from` clause, but not after it.  (Note:  I replaced the `,` in the `from` with `cross join` because I abhor commas in the `from` clause.)

By the way, SQL Server solves this problem with the `cross apply` operator.

Comment: to complete the picture: `cross apply` is SQL Server's implementation of the `lateral join` defined in the SQL standard

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Cool.  And I see that Postgres 9.3 has support for it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I completely forgot about cross join.